# root password using Nodejs mscdex/ssh2

Tags: node.js, express, npm

I'm trying to login as root on a remote linux machine using [mscdex/ssh2](https://github.com/mscdex/ssh2), the steps I'm trying to achieve are :

1. connect via ssh to the remot machine
2. execute command as root user

but I'm failing in the second part, I can't get to put the password right, here is my code.

```
  conn.on('ready', function() {
    conn.exec('sudo -s ls /', { pty: true }, (err, stream) => {
      if (err) {
       res.send(err);
      }

      stream.on('exit', (code, signal) => {
       console.log(`Stream :: close :: code: ${code}, signal: ${signal}`);
      });

      stream.on('data', data => {

        // here it's where supposedly the password should be given
        stream.write('r00tpa$$word' + '\n');
        console.log(data);
      });

    });
  }).connect({
    host: '192.168.100.100',
    username: 'fakeAdmin',
    password: 'fakePassword'
  });
```

I already have the pty option set to true, but I'm only getting error messages on the promt.

**Update :**

here is my new code snippet :

```
const Client = require('ssh2').Client;
const conn = new Client();

const encode = 'utf8';

conn.on('ready', () => {
  conn.shell(false, { pty: true }, (err, stream) => {
    if (err) { console.log(err) }

    stream.on('data', (data) => {
      process.stdout.write(data.toString(encode));
    });

    stream.write('ls -a\n');
    stream.write('uptime\n');
    stream.write('su\n'); // here nothing seems to happen
    stream.write('rootPassword\n'); // here also
    stream.write('cd /tmp && ls\n');
  });
})
.connect({
  host: "192.168.100.100",
  username: "username",
  password: "usernamePassword"
});
```

I've managed to perform the several commands part in  a much cleaner way, I even raised an issue on the library github page [.shell command "su" loses interaction](https://github.com/mscdex/ssh2/issues/661) , but now what it's happening it's kinda weird, I can run as many commands as I what, but when I run a "su" command nothing seems to happen, does somebody step into this before?, or what I'm I doing wrong ?
Sorry if I couldn't explain myself right.

Regards.

Comment: Are you certain the remote machine accepts root over ssh?  That's generally considered a security hole.

Comment: yes, I've tested manually through my local machine bash and I can login without a problem. but using this library the longest I can get is that the console.log(data); logs "bash-4.1# "

Comment: What about just using username `root` wile connection itself? Does that work?

Comment: Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46459348/entering-password-programmatically-in-ssh2-nodejs), probably it will point you to some idea

Comment: Have you tried explicitly using the root username option with su that @DushyantBangal suggested? `su root\n`

Comment: in most cases the sysadmins block the root connection via ssh as first user, I've try the solution suggested above, and it worked, but it's not an option due that what I'm asking for is to login as root once I achieved the normal user connection.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `node-ssh`. I've used it with no problem before and it is more modern as well because it has a promise-based asynchronous interface.

You also should connect directly to the root user if you need to perform root actions, unless you have a user that does not ask for a password when performing `sudo`, for example with EC2 instances that use the Ubuntu AMI which comes by default with an `ubuntu` user without password (you authenticate via ssh keypair).

Trying to log in by command and inputting the password in plain text is not a good idea. Also consider adding an ssh key to the root user to authenticate with a private key instead of a password.

```
const SSH = require('node-ssh')

const ssh = new SSH()  

ssh.connect({
  host: '<host>',
  username: 'root',
  password: '<password>'
}).then(() => ssh.exec('your command'))
```

Comment: Ok, I'll try it and I'll tell you in one day or two what happen, thanks for your response

Comment: I've had try it to make it work, but I'm still not figure out how to perform these steps:
1) connect as a normal user
2) switch to root user
3) perform some actions as root

How did you do it to give password when root switch is made ?

Comment: @flaalf if you want to connect as root user you should do it directly, so `username` would be `root` and `password` would be the root password. What's your reasoning to connect first as a normal user?

Comment: in most cases sysadmins block the root connection directly via ssh, that's because the root connection at start is not an option

Comment: @flaalf well, then you should probably have a key-authenticated sudoer user and use `sudo` instead of trying to do `su`. Writing the password directly seems to me like a very bad idea, worse than giving direct root access or having a key-authenticated sudoer user.

I read what you wrote about `sudo` being slower and I don't think that's really the case, at least in a substantial amount.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a way to perform what I was searching for, here is the code :

```
const Client = require('ssh2').Client;
const conn = new Client();

const encode = 'utf8';
const connection = {
  host: '100.10.101.11',
  username: 'admin',
  password: 'c0mm0nU53rP455'
}

conn.on('ready', function() {
  // avoid the use of console.log due to it adds a new line at the end of
  // the message
  process.stdout.write('Connection :: ready');

  let password = 'y0urR007p455w0rd';
  let command = '';
  let pwSent = false;
  let su = false;
  let commands = [
    `su`,
    `ls /root`,
    `touch /media/delete_me.txt`,
    `rm /media/delete_me.txt` // be carefull with this type of commands
  ];

  conn.shell((err, stream) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }

    stream.on('exit', function (code) {
      process.stdout.write('Connection :: exit');
      conn.end();
    });

    stream.on('data', function(data) {
      process.stdout.write(data.toString(encode));

      // handle su password prompt
      if (command.indexOf('su') !== -1 && !pwSent) {
         /*
         * if su has been sent a data event is triggered but the
         * first event is not the password prompt, this will ignore the
         * first event and only respond when the prompt is asking
         * for the password
         */
         if (command.indexOf('su') > -1) {
            su = true;
         }
         if (data.indexOf(':') >= data.length - 2) {
            pwSent = true;
            stream.write(password + '\n');
         }
      } else {
        // detect the right condition to send the next command
        let dataLength = data.length > 2;
        let commonCommand = data.indexOf('$') >= data.length - 2;
        let suCommand = data.indexOf('#') >= data.length - 2;

        if (dataLength && (commonCommand || suCommand )) {

          if (commands.length > 0) {
            command = commands.shift();
            stream.write(command + '\n');

          } else {
            // su requires two exit commands to close the session
            if (su) {
               su = false;
               stream.write('exit\n');
            } else {
               stream.end('exit\n');
            }
          }
        }
      }
    });

    // first command
    command = commands.shift();
    stream.write(command + '\n');
  });
}).connect(connection);
```